# how to fix the error of android apk Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android-studio, apk, release

Installation failed with message Failed to commit install session 2575737 with command cmd package install-commit 2575737.

> Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl2575737.tmp/0_base-en has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.